# Access ListView from another Class for a Search Function - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'd like to implement a simple Search Function in my App.
I already implemented all the Layout Related things and it works without problems.
Now, I'd like to find Items from a `ListView` using the Search Function.

The Problem is, that my `ListView` is not in the same Class. When i try to access my `ListView` from the other Class, i keep get a `NullPointerException`.

This is what i have in my MainActivity:

```
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
    {

      //  new otherActivity().listView.clearTextFilter(); NullPointerException



    }
    else
    {
    //   new otherActivity().listView.setFilterText(newText.toString()); NullPointerException

    }

    return true;
}
```

In my otherActivity, i do have `ListView listView;` outside the `onCreate()` Method and `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` inside the `onCreate()` Method.

I also tried to put the whole `ListView` outside the `onCreate()` Method but that ended up in a `NullPointerException` aswell.

Comment: You should specify action that you want to take by sending parameters with intent in bundle, you can not reference your listView from another activity. just start otherActivity and pass your filter text

Comment: You should save the data either in database or standalone class which are being displayed inside ListView then perform filter on that data instead of trying to access the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible ways that you can use `ListView` in a class that have its reference.

```
1.) Pass reference of ListView in other class constructor
2.) create a static getter method of ListView in your Activity having ListView
3.) Use Application class to setter and getter of ListView instance
4.) Another way is have an instance of Activity with as static getter method and
    use that to get instance of your ListView in another Class.
```

These above mentioned possible ways may vary depending on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
 new otherActivity()
```

You are not supposed to create an Activity in this way.

Use an Intent instead to start your Activity.